# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2)  error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, screen-resolution, pyautogui

this is my code and I have a problem. What is the solution for it, please?
I try to make a screen recorder:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyautogui

codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
out = cv2.VideoWriter("Recorded.avi", codec, 60, (1366,768))
cv2.namedWindow("Recording", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Recording", 480, 270)

while True:
     img = pyautogui.screenshot #capturing screenshot
     frame = np.array(img) # converting the image into numpy array representation
     frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # converting the BGR image into RGB image
     out.write(frame) # writing the RBG image to file
     cv2.imshow('Recording', frame) # display screen/frame being recorded
     if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'): # Wait for the user to press 'q' key to stop the recording
          break

 out.release() # closing the video file
 cv2.destroyAllWindows() # destroying the recording window
```

The problem here:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mhmdj\PycharmProjects\learn\main.py", line 13, in
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # converting the BGR image into RGB image
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2)  error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'

Overload resolution failed:

src data type = 17 is not supported
Expected Ptrcv::UMat for argument 'src'

Comment: Can you try doing `frame = np.array(img, dtype="uint8")`?

Comment: data type 17 might be CV_8SC3, which is an odd type

Comment: are you sure you don't have to do a **call** here?: `img = pyautogui.screenshot`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try loading the image with `cv2.imread()` rather than the np.array() to see if that works since the examples use this method:

```
img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Anders Elmgren thank you, bro, I tried it and it works, but the question is the program when works it's just open the image but did not record and I want the solution to the 
problem previous